# Cannot create custom module in Magento

Tags: php, xml, magento

I'm pretty new to Magento and I've started learning to develop custom modules for the frontend. I've followed several guides and for some reason, none of them are working. It seems as though loadLayout and renderLayout are causing problems. I'm not sure if this is because I have a file in the wrong location, or what the problem is. I've tried loading the pages magento.x/helloworld magento.x/helloworld/index magento.x/index.php/helloworld. I'm getting a broken version of the default site. If I replace the lLayout and rLayout with an echo it works just fine. This is what I have:

app/code/local/Wrapids/Helloworld/etc/config.xml

```
<config>
<modules>
    <Wrapids_Helloworld>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Wrapids_Helloworld>
</modules>
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <helloworld>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Wrapids_Helloworld</module>
                <frontName>helloworld</frontName>
            </args>
        </helloworld>
    </routers>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <helloworld>
                <file>helloworld.xml</file>
            </helloworld>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>
</config>
```

app/code/local/Wrapids/Helloworld/controllers/IndexController.php

```
<?php 
class Wrapids_Helloworld_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action 
    {
     public function indexAction() 
     {
      $this->loadLayout();
      $this->renderLayout();
     }
    }
?>
```

/app/design/frontend/default/default/template/helloworld/page.phtml

```
text
```

app/design/frontend/default/default/layout/helloworld.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="helloworld/helloworld" name="hello" template="helloworld/page.phtml">
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

app/code/local/Wrapids/Helloworld/Block/Helloworld.php

```
<?php
    class Wrapids_Helloworld_Block_Helloworld extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
    {
    }
?>
```

Comment: You closing tag for the layout xml (app/design/frontend/default/default/layout/helloworld.xml) is broken, check if that is the issue.

Comment: Oops, nope. Typo when I entered it in on here.

Comment: The problem at your layout file. First of all, you remove root node, as far as I remember it's main node. And I don't see <wrapids_helloworld_index> at layout.

Comment: @v.kondratyuk: I have tried wrapids_helloworld_index as well as default. Neither of them are yielding changes. As far as removing the root node it should leave me with an entirely blank page. It doesn't look like the layout.xml may even be being processed.

Comment: make an error at helloworld.xml and check if you can see an error, also check cache.

Comment: 1) cache if cache is flushed/disabled (if this is development environment) 2) Try <wrapids_helloworld_index_index> and go to helloworld/index/index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not quite understood your goal but you can try it:
app/design/frontend/default/default/layout/helloworld.xml

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="root"> 
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>helloworld/page.phtml</template></action> 
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

Comment: Want you replace block for this template like <block type="page/html".. with <block type="your_module/your_block" to enhance functional?

Comment: So far any type change doesn't matter, nothing that uses type="" has worked so far. Only the above method with <action method=setTemplate

Comment: Magento Team described as well method setType for change type of block but my attemps was unsuccessful.

Comment: I have in another question what I believe to be the root of this problem posted. The above <block...> xml layout is working for some of the custom modules I have installed on the system I'm working with. Once I have time to take a look at them more in depth I'll update this with the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Move your template and layout files to [your_package]/default or [your_package]/[your_theme]

Answer (score 0):

Have you added Wrapids_Helloworld.xml file to app/etc/modules with the following code? This must be present in order to load the module

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Wrapids_Helloworld>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Wrapids_Helloworld>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Comment: Yes, I mentioned in the post that it was working with echo, I didn't feel I needed to add that code.

Comment: I copied these files to one of my local magento installation (enterprise version) and removing root block caused problems. Removing footer showed page without footer. It seems everything is working. To define action I used `<helloworld_index_index>` and inside `<remove name="footer" />`. With this in `/helloworld/index/index` I saw page without footer.